# Is there pastebin software for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, pastebin

Pastebin is software that allows a person to save clips of code from many languages, or just text files, and share them with the public as read-only files. See [pastebin.org](http://pastebin.org).

- Ubuntu 14.04 running as a VM.
- Machine does not have a full registered domain name but has it's own IP address.
- I only want our company employees to access it from within our company via a browser, not from their homes.
- We want to do this to share private code within the company.
- Installing from Ubuntu repo preferred.
- I'd like syntax highlighting for Perl, SQL, and other languages.

Questions.

- Do I need to set up a web server for this to run on top of? Because I have never tested the web server part. Or will the pastebin software work by itself.
- I'd like to have multiple users. Each user can have the option to keep pastes forever, or expire them as they like.
- I'd like the option to limit number or size of pastes by user if storage space becomes an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to set up [Stikked](https://github.com/claudehohl/Stikked):

> Stikked is an Open-Source PHP Pastebin, with the aim of keeping a
>   simple and easy to use user interface.
>
> Stikked allows you to easily share code with anyone you wish.

The project seems to be actively maintained on GitHub.

Comment: Hm. I did find an example screen here: Example screen: http://www.maketecheasier.com/run-your-own-pastebin-with-stikked/

Comment: @Bulrush: You can even try it here: http://paste.scratchbook.ch/

Comment: I tried the sample website, but there was not username and password facility. Does the user simply type in their name each time? How would they get a list of pastes they own to edit one later?

Answer (score 1):

Since you edited your question adding the information that you preferred installing an application from the Ubuntu repos, I will suggest Nautilus Pastebin Configurator (*nautilus-pastebin-configurator*) from the default Ubuntu 14.04 repositories, even though Nautilus Pastebin Configurator doesn't have as many advanced features which you require as Stikked has. Nautilus Pastebin Configurator  is a Nautilus extension written in Python, which allows users to upload text-only files to a pastebin service just by right-clicking on them. After sending the files, a notification will be shown and the paste URL copied into the clipboard.

Users can also customize the extension's behavior just by using nautilus-pastebin-configurator, an easy-to-use configuration tool.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering how many choices I got for "Delete after" and the screen shot I found did not answer that question.